# HSTRING de-allocation with WindowsCreateStringReference vs WindowsCreateString

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

In my WinRT API I have to create and return `HSTRING` values. So far I have been using `WindowsCreateString` to create `HSTRING` value and deleting it manually with `WindowsDeleteString`.

[WindowsCreateStringReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winstring/nf-winstring-windowscreatestringreference) looks quite handy in terms one does not have to delete `HSTRING` manually.

> You don't need to call the WindowsDeleteString function to de-allocate a fast-pass HSTRING created by the WindowsCreateStringReference function.

Can anyone elaborate on what is `fast-pass string` and how and when it actually gets de-allocated?

Another question that comes here is when should I prefer `WindowsCreateString` over `WindowsCreateStringReference`?

Comment: `WindowsCreateStringReference` is the moral equivalent of [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). It doesn't own resources, but provides an observable interface to the underlying resource only. Since fast-pass strings (and `string_view`s) don't own resources, you are responsible for managing object lifetimes. The referenced resource must live at least as long as the view into it. If you are returning an `HSTRING` from your interface you cannot establish this (unless you are willing to leak memory).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Indeed I need to return HSTRING and Im stick to WindowsCreate/DeleteString API pairs

Comment: That's only partially correct. You don't need to call `WindowsDeleteString`. That's the responsibility of your clients. When you return an `HSTRING`, you are transferring ownership. A client is free to choose however they want to handle the responsibility. They can use the raw `HSTRING` and manually perform cleanup, or bind it to an object with automatic resource management (like [winrt::hstring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/hstring) in C++/WinRT).

Comment: @IInspectable  Clients receive C++/CLI `Platform::String^` value from my APIs over `WRL`. Actually, I am not sure how that `HSTRING` to `Platform::String` transformation is happening here. Do you still think I don't need to worry about memory leak and get rid off `WindowsDeleteString`?

Comment: I'm assuming, that your clients use C++/CX (not C++/CLI). Regardless, when returning a string, you are always returning an `HSTRING` handle. Depending on the language *projection* used by the client, the raw resource looks like a natural type (e.g. [Platform::String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/platform-string-class) in case of C++/CX). There is no conversion at all; `Platform::String` still manages the raw `HSTRING` it received. This is transparent, and you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: [Strings (C++/CX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/strings-c-cx) is worth reading, if you are indeed using C++/CX.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the clarification. It was indeed helpful. Would you like to write down your comments as answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

A 'fast-pass' string doesn't manage the lifetime of its string - it simply creates a wrapper around whatever underlying string you give it. This wrapper is very lightweight.

This means 2 things - firstly you don't need to delete the `HSTRING` (as it doesn't own the underlying string) but more importantly you must keep the underlying string alive and unchanged whilst the fast-pass string is being used.

So its useful for if you already have a string (say a const char* in the rodata section, or from another source who's lifetime is strictly greater than the lifetime of the HSTRING). But its just an optimisation to avoid a copy.

MY recommendation - if you only care about lifetime and correctly free'ing the string when done - is to use [`Microsoft::WRL::Wrapper::HString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/windows/hstring-class?view=vs-2017) class which provides a nice C++ style RAII wrapper around raw `HSTRING`'s and will correctly free them when done. Then using member functions `Detach`, `Get`, `GetAddressOf`, etc you can then interact with other APIs which expect raw `HSTRING`s.

If you do care about speed aswell there is always a `Microsoft::WRL::Wrapper::HStringReference` class which duplicates the `WindowsCreateStringReference` funcitonality, but again with a nice c++ RAII object.

Comment: The question is tagged C++/WinRT. [winrt::hstring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/hstring) is probably a better fit than the semi-manual WRL implementations.

Comment: As per my observation, as soon as object of  `Microsoft::WRL::Wrapper::HString` class is destroyed, its atached `HSTRING` also becomes invalid. That sounds pretty much similar to wrapper given by `WindowsCreateStringReference`, but just little bit more elegant.